# Prove that $\{x \in X \mid f(x) < g(x)\}$ is an open set in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $Y$ be an ordered set in the order topology. Let $f,g:X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous functions form a topological space $X$. 
Prove that $\{x \in X \mid f(x) < g(x)\}$ is an open set in $X$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Since $Y$ is an ordered set in the Order Topology, then $Y$ is Hausdorff.

So, $\forall a \neq b \in Y \,\, \exists$open sets $U,V \subset Y$ such that $a \in U$, $b \in V$, and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Pick open subsets $U,V \subset Y$ with $a \in U$ and $b \in V$.

Since $f,g$ are continuous functions, then $f^{-1}(U)$, $g^{-1}(V) \subset X$ are open.

Let $x \in f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1}(V)$ which is also open. Then, $x \in f^{-1}(U)$ and $x \in g^{-1}(U)$.

So, $f(x) \in U \subset Y$ and $g(x) \in g^{-1}(V) \subset Y$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and $f(x) \neq g(x)$.

So, either $f(x)<g(x)$ or $f(x)>g(x)$.
Without loss of generality, suppose $f(x)<g(x)$.

Then, $x \in \{x \in X \mid f(x)<g(x)\}$

$\therefore x \in f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1}(V) \subset \{x \in X \mid f(x)<g(x)\} \subset X$.

$\therefore \{x \in X \mid f(x)<g(x)\}$ is open in $X$. $\blacksquare$

---

I wasn't given any feedback on my proof, so I am trying to see if this is well written. I would also like to know if the WLOG makes sense to use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m afraid that it does not work: it’s true that $f(x)\ne g(x)$ whenever $x\in f^{-1}[U]\cap g^{-1}[V]$, but it’s entirely possible that there are $x_0,x_1\in f^{-1}[U]\cap g^{-1}[V]$ such that $f(x_0)<g(x_0)$, but $f(x_1)>g(x_1)$. (It would be a good exercise to construct an example of this phenomenon.)

There is also a notational problem: when you write

$$x\in\{x\in X:f(x)<g(x)\}\,,$$

you’re using $x$ to mean two completely different things in the same expression. The first $x$ refers to a specific point of $X$; the instances of $x$ between the curly braces are instances of a dummy variable used to define the set. It should be

$$x\in\{u\in X:f(u)<g(u)\}$$

or the like.

Let $A=\{x\in X:f(x)<g(x)\}$. The most straightforward way to show that $A$ is open is to let $x\in A$ be arbitrary and find an open nbhd of $x$ contained in $A$. To do this we will use disjoint open nbhds of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, but that isn’t enough: we have to choose them a bit carefully.

If there is a $u\in Y$ such that $f(x)<u<g(x)$, let $U=(\leftarrow,u)$ and $V=(u,\to)$, the open rays to the left and to the right of $u$; clearly $f(x)\in U$, $g(x)\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. If there is no such $u$, then $g(x)$ is the immediate successor of $f(x)$ in $Y$, and we let $U=\big(\leftarrow,g(x)\big)$ and $V=\big(f(x),\to\big)$; again we have $f(x)\in U$, $g(x)\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. Note that in both cases $y_0<y_1$ whenever $y_0\in U$ and $y_1\in V$: this is the fact that makes the argument work and that was missing in your construction.

Let $W=f^{-1}[U]\cap g^{-1}[V]$; clearly $W$ is an open nbhd of $x$. If $z\in W$, then $f(z)\in U$ and $g(z)\in V$, so $f(z)<g(z)$, and therefore $z\in A$. Thus, $W\subseteq A$, and $A$ is open in $X$.